# Filtering the data on the basis of daterangepicker in laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, daterangepicker

I want to apply date range filter to my specific page .. There is just one date range picker which allows you to select a range from the calender and it shows in a single variable. i am getting the data in that variable but i dont know the exact way to filter my database data by splitting single variable value in two values ( from and to ) .

This is my input box --

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="daterange" value="01/01/2021 - 01/15/2021" />
```

Below is my specific script for daterange -

```
 $(function() {
            $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
                "startDate": "11/01/2021",
                "endDate": "11/07/2021",
                opens: 'left'
            }, function(start, end, label) {
               console.log('New date range selected: ' + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' (predefined range: ' + label + ')');
                axios.get('/fetchdata')
                    .then(response => {
                        data = this.form;
                    })
            });
        });
```

This is my web.php

```
Route::get('fetchdata', 'AccessoryController@fetch_data')->name('accessory.date.filter');
```

and this is my controller code where i need help , for now daterange picker is working. Its giving me correct selection in console. "New date range selected: 2021-11-04 to 2021-11-10 (predefined range: undefined)"

and my route is also working with return 'test' but i dont know how to get data at the back end.

```
 public function fetch_data(Request $request) 
   {
       //return 'test';
       return $request->all(); // This returns nothing
       $user = Auth::user();
       $storesID = $user->storesID->pluck('id');
       $stores = $user->stores;
       return $request->daterange;
       $accessory = AccessoryRequest::where('request_date', ">=", $request->startDate)->where('date', "<=", $request->endDate)->get(); //how can i filter
       return $accessory;
       return view('accessorydetails.index')
       ->with('stores', $stores)
       ->with('accessories', $accessories);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not put any parameters to the server:

```
axios.get('/fetchdata', {
        params: {
            startDate: start.format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
            endDate: end.format('YYYY-MM-DD')
        }
    }).then(response => {
        data = this.form;
    });
```

Regarding `AccessoryRequest`, I guess you mean Accessory Eloquent object to work with the database

`$accessory = AccessoryRequest::where('request_date', ">=", $request->startDate)->where('date', "<=", $request->endDate)->get(); //how can i filter`

I am not sure how the name of the date field is, but idea is to do smth like

```
$accessory = AccessoryRequest::where('created_at', ">=", $request->get('startDate'))
    ->where('created_at', "<=", $request->get('endDate'))
    ->get();
```

Comment: If i check for return $request->all(), it still returns me empty json response.

Comment: if you open `<your_local_host>/fetchdata?startDate=2020-12-12&endDate=2021-02-01` then $request->all() should return data. Have you checked in the network tab of the developer tool of the browser if those parameters were sent?

Comment: Then we do need to change web.php because we are not passing parameters while calling route and in the network tab, no parameters are being sent. Its showing me fetchdata as file name which returns nothing in response.

Comment: @Yashima the issue in JS, web.php is correct. I've updated my comment. please try 
(The issue was how we pass parameters with axios https://github.com/axios/axios)

Comment: I dont know why but get method was not working for me !! I did it with post method rest as you said. So thanks for the help !

Comment: @Yashima with GET there is an extra index `params` and POST doesn't need it, so different syntax. I'm glad you've managed to get it working!

Comment: okey i got it !! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

In web.php --

```
Route::post('fetchdata', 'AccessoryController@fetch_data')->name('accessory.date.filter');
```

and in script file

```
 $(function () {
            $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
            "startDate": "11/01/2021",
            "endDate": "11/07/2021"
            }, function(start, end, label) {
            console.log('New date range selected: ' + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' (predefined range: ' + label + ')');
            axios.post('/fetchdata/', {
                        startDate: start.format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
                        endDate: end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
                    }).then(response => {
                        $(location).attr('href', '/accessory')
                        //console.log(startDate);
                    });
            });
        });
```

Axios was not working with get method.